# Constructors in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

In Java we can use constructors in order to pass initial values into a class. Is this possible in swift?

For example, in the line below I am trying to add an object, which should include all the values you can see in the function that is within it, into an array called arrayOfMedia.

```
self.arrayOfMedia.append(Media().getUsersMedia(image: image!, postNum: anyPosts.key, userID: user))
```

I cannot do this however and get the error below.

> Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'Media'

Comment: Yes, they are called initialisers, the problem you have is, in you example, `Media` doesn't seem to take any values via its initialiser, just like in Java, if the class's constructor doesn't provide the functionality there's nothing you can do.  The reason you are likely getting the error is, `getUsersMedia` is probably retuning `void`, hence you can't add it to the array

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Media`, but are you asking if you can create a `convenience` initializer?

Comment: Can you show what's returned from `getUsersMedia`?

Comment: getUsersMedia returns nothing I was using it to set the values inside of teh class. @MadProgrammer check teh update to question

Comment: *"I do not want to have to initialize the class as the values going into it vary (sometimes a video and sometimes a image)*" ... okay, so that makes no sense, you have a class which is a container for some type of data, why not supply two different initialisers for the two different use cases ... just like you would in Java?

Comment: ok provide that as answer @ MadProgrammer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not want to have to initialize the class as the values going into it vary (sometimes a video and sometimes a image)

Okay, so that makes no sense, you have a `class` which is a container for some data, some of which is optional (either you have an image or a video), why not supply two different initialisers for the two different use cases ... just like you would in Java?

There's a few ways you "might" achieve this, this is just one...

```
class Media {
    var image: UIImage?
    var video: Data?
    let postKey: Int
    let userId: Int

    internal required init(postKey: Int, userId: Int) {
        self.postKey = postKey
        self.userId = userId
    }

    convenience init(image: UIImage, postKey: Int, userId: Int) {
        self.init(postKey: postKey, userId: userId)
        self.image = image
    }

    convenience init(video: Data, postKey: Int, userId: Int) {
        self.init(postKey: postKey, userId: userId)
        self.video = video
    }
}
```

Also, note, you could have simply provided a single initialiser, something like...

```
init(image: UIImage? = nil, video: Data? = nil, postKey: Int, userId: Int) {...}
```

but this doesn't constraint the user to one or the other type (they can still pass `nil` for both values)

Another approach might be to make use of a `protocol` to describe the basic/common properties of `Media` and then implement the different requirements (directly as `struct`s or `class`s or indirectly as additional `protocols`)

For example...

```
protocol Media  {
    var postKey: Int { get }
    var userId: Int { get }
}

struct VideoMedia: Media {
    let postKey: Int
    let userId: Int
    let video: Data
}

struct ImageMedia: Media {
    let postKey: Int
    let userId: Int
    let image: UIImage
}
```

Comment: SO I have been making these changes to my app, but got to a point where I need to access the #image of a certain image so I can add that to what will be added tp the DB namely a jason like image1: URL... but with these init's I cannot as when I call teh Media class it asks to be initialize. Whats a fix to this?

Comment: If you have a reference to the `Media` object, why not reference the `image` property?  Or are you trying to decode the JSON?  I'm not sure I understand the problem you've gotten yourself into.  The example above "assumes" you will have to populate the object with the data when it's initialised (ie, you can't have an empty `Media` class).  Oh and by the way - I'm "assuming" the data types, as I have zero context of the actual data you are trying to capture

Comment: I will add new question that adresses this as I think it is not good here or do you think otherwise?

Comment: @neburRB I'd more context before I could provide more help, so, yeah, a new question might be helpful

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234459/how-to-have-initializers-in-a-class-but-still-be-able-to-access-the-classs-valu Here is teh question

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, in this case I would use enums to wrap your media types.

```
enum MediaType {
    case image(UIImage)
    case video(Data) 
}
```

Then you have Type safe access without requiring optionals:

```
struct Media {
    let postKey: Int
    let userId: Int
    let mediaType: MediaType
}

let video = Media(postKey: 1, userId: 2, mediaType: .video(dataVariable))
let image = Media(postKey: 2, userId: 3, mediaType: .image(imageVariable))
```