# How to have initializers in a class but still be able to access the class's values

Tags: swift, class

I have a function that only needs to access one value inside an object with has initializers.

```
ImageUploadManager().sendImages(self.images, postID: postID, image: Media().postImage)
```

However doing so yields the following error:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Media' with no arguments

So my question is: is it possible to access a value as I do here withought having to initialize?

Comment: type Media.init press escape and let Xcode autocomplete for you. If you have a static property or method type `Media.` and press escape and check the available methods

Comment: Media.init(image: <#T##UIImage#>) is what I get: I do have multiple inits though? does convinience do anything here?

Comment: you need to pass an `UIImage` object 
 to the Media initializer. What is your UIImage object called ? Is it postImage? if so `Media(image: postImage)`

Comment: Why do you need to create a new instance of `Media`?  Wouldn't `postImage` either be `nil` or a default value?  I'm not sure what you're trying to do makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that needs to be done is to declare a init withough any paramaters:

```
    class Media: NSObject {

    override init() { }
}
```